# How to create list in both model classes in one another

Tags: java

I have 2 bean classes- Country & city. I need to keep city list in Country class. ANd also when i am setting the city information I need to set the country name, so need country inside city class too. How to do it?
Below are the codes:

**Country.java**

```
 public class Country {

private String name;
private String about;
 ArrayList<City> cities;

public Country()
{
    cities = new ArrayList<City>();
}

public Country(String name, String about)
{
    this.name= name;
    this.about = about;
}


public int getNoOfCities()
{
    return cities.size();
}


public long getNoOfCitizens()
{ Long aPop= 0L;
    //Long aPopulation = cities.get 
    for(City aCity: cities)
    {
       aPop += aCity.getPopulation();
    }
    return aPop;
}



public String getName(){
    return name;

} 
public String getAbout(){
    return about;
}
}
```

**City.java**

```
 public class City {

    private String name;
    private String about;
    private Long population;

    public City(String name, String about, Long population)
    {
        this.name= name;
        this.name = about;
        this.population = population;


    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;

    } 
    public String getAbout(){
        return about;

    } 
    public Long getPopulation(){
        return population;
    } 
 }
```

How can i solve it? Someone told me something like ViewObject but don't know what it is or whether its going to solve. Help me :-)

**Country Entry/details UI**
1. Name *(Entry)*
2. About *(Entry)*
3. List of every country
4. For each country in the listView- a details UI (**Details UI**) which will have:
     4.1. Name
     4.2 Number of cities under this country
     4.3. Number of population in this country(WHich will be the sum of all City population under the country)

**City Entry UI**
1. Name *(Entry)*
2. About *(Entry)*
3. Population *(Entry)*
4. Country *(Drop down)*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I perfectly understand the question, but the easiest thing I can think of is adding reference to the Country to the City. If you think about it, it makes perfect sense - every City lies in a Country so it should be impossible to have a City without Country.

```
public class City {

private String name;
private String about;
private Long population;
private Country country;

public City(String name, String about, Long population, Country country)
{
    this.name= name;
    this.name = about;
    this.population = population;
    this.country=country;
    country.addCity(this);
}
```

Comment: I Already have city list inside Country. And i heard that its bad concept in oop to use the opposite reference back to the another class(as in, Country reference in city.java)

Comment: Please explain this sentence "when i am setting the city information I need to set the country name". Where? You want to set the country name in a field of the city?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a model factory class. They can be used to populate and create the model for the controller. e.g:

```
public class CountryModelFactory {

    public static Country populateCountryModel() {
        // code to populate the Country model.
        // then return the Country model.
   }
}
```

The advantage of using a Model Factory type of class is that you can separate the model from the controller through a medium which can then populate a number of similar model depending on the request.